# How to sort ArrayList of strings with priority that obtained from a HashMap?

Tags: java, performance

I have an ArrayList of ArrayLists and inside those ArrayLists I store Strings, and I would like to sort those string according to their priority that I store on a HashMap. Is there a efficient way to accomplish this task simply iterating over them?

Comment: How do you store the priority in ``HashMap`` ?

Comment: I store the frequencies of strings like A:4 B:3, basically their occurences in all arraylists.

Comment: Please provide some sample code of your example :) It's understandable but that makes it way easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a `HashMap` with priorities you could do this:

```
List<List<String>> listList = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> listOne = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
List<String> listTwo = Arrays.asList("D", "D", "D", "B");

listList.add(listOne);
listList.add(listTwo);

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", 1);
    map.put("B", 2);
    map.put("C", 1);
    map.put("D", 4);


listList.forEach(list -> list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(map::get)));
```

Note that for this to work, you have to have all the strings from list in your `Map` with priorities, otherwise you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem correctly, this should do the trick. If you consider this efficient is depending on the performance bounds you have to meet.

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> priorities = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    priorities.put("A", 1);
    priorities.put("B", 2);
    priorities.put("C", 3);

    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    list.add(Arrays.asList("A", "C", "B"));
    list.add(Arrays.asList("B", "A", "B"));
    list.add(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));

    list.forEach(x -> x.sort((string1, string2) -> {
        return priorities.get(string1) - priorities.get(string2);
    }));

    System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    arraylist.add("a");
    arraylist.add("a");
    arraylist.add("a");
    arraylist.add("b");
    arraylist.add("c");
    arraylist.add("c");
    arraylist.add("c");
    arraylist.add("c");
    arraylist.add("d");
    arraylist.add("d");

    Map<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("a",3);
    hashMap.put("b",1);
    hashMap.put("c",4);
    hashMap.put("d",2);

    Collections.sort(arraylist, (o1, o2) -> {
        int i = hashMap.get(o1) < hashMap.get(o2) ? 1 : -1;
        return i;
    });
```

this gives the following output:
[c, c, c, c, a, a, a, d, d, b]

Comment: You can further improve this by simply using `hashMap.get(o1) - hashMap.get(o2)` which also correctly handles equality by returning a 0.